# Remove "doi:" prefix string in formatted bibliographic entries

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, elsarticle, doi

I want to remove "doi:" prefix string in references

```
\documentclass[1p]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}

\biboptions{numbers,sort&compress}

\modulolinenumbers[5]

\journal{Journal of Sound and Vibration}

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
\bibliography{myrefer}
```

```
@article{tichy1983active,
  title={Active noise cancellation in ducts},
  author={Tichy, Jiri and Warnaka, Glenn E and Poole, Lynn A},
  journal={The Journal of the Acoustical Society of America},
  volume={74},
  number={S1},
  pages={S25--S25},
  year={1983},
  publisher={Acoustical Society of America},
  doi={https://doi.org/10.1121/1.2020873}
}
```

How can I remove "doi:"

I want to print only https://doi.org/10.1121/1.2020873

Comment: @Mico that doesn't matter as hyperref loads url anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two approaches to achieving your formatting objective.

1. Change the field

   ```
    doi={https://doi.org/10.1121/1.2020873}
   ```

   to

   ```
    note={\url{https://doi.org/10.1121/1.2020873}}
   ```

   This can get tedious if your bibliography has more than a handful of entries with a `doi` field.
2. Modify a copy of the file `elsarticle-num.bst`, as follows:

- Find the file `elsarticle-num.bst` in your TeX distribution. Make a copy of this file and call the copy, say, `elsarticle-num-nodoiprefix.bst`. (You're free to come up with a different name...)
- Open `elsarticle-num-nodoiprefix.bst` in a text editor. The program you use to edit your tex files will do fine.
- Within `elsarticle-num-nodoiprefix.bst`, find the following line (likely line 64):

  ```
   "doi:" 'doiprefix :=      % text prefix printed before DOI ref
  ```

  Change it to

  ```
   "" 'doiprefix :=          % no text prefix printed before DOI ref
  ```
- Save the file `elsarticle-num-nodoiprefix.bst` in the directory where your main tex file is located.
- In the main tex file, change the instruction

  ```
  \bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
  ```

  to

  ```
  \bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num-nodoiprefix}
  ```

  and perform a full recompile cycle - LateX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more -- to fully propagate all changes.

Happy BibTeXing.

---

Here's an MWE (minimum working example) that illustrates the outcome of using the second approach. (The first approach produces the same output.) Note that I have set `doi={10.1121/1.2020873}` as the software automatically inserts the `https://doi.org/` prefix.

[image]

```
\documentclass[1p]{elsarticle}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{myrefer.bib}
@article{tichy1983active,
  title={Active noise cancellation in ducts},
  author={Tichy, Jiri and Warnaka, Glenn E. and Poole, Lynn A.},
  journal={The Journal of the Acoustical Society of America},
  volume={74},
  number={S1},
  pages={S25--S25},
  year={1983},
  publisher={Acoustical Society of America},
  doi={10.1121/1.2020873}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{natbib} % <- this package is loaded automatically by elsarticle class
\usepackage{xurl}    % <-- use xurl, not url
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{hyperref} % <-- load hyperref just once, and _last_
\biboptions{numbers,sort&compress}
\modulolinenumbers[5]
\hypersetup{colorlinks,allcolors=blue}

\journal{Journal of Sound and Vibration}

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num-nodoiprefix}

\begin{document}
\cite{tichy1983active}
\bibliography{myrefer}
\end{document}
```